# React Native Firebase - When to set UserId and UserProperties

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, react-native-firebase

We have a React Native app which I'm setting up the tracking for. I'm used to doing web of GA4 via GTM.

For event-based parameters, we would obviously send them with each event as they are ... event-based.
When it comes to the UserId and other UserProperties would these be sent with each event, or would we send this once?

For example, in GTM there a config tag where you can set the UserId and any UserProperties, and these get sent for every event.

Is this necessary for an app? In our app, the user has to log in to use the app. In that case, could we just set the UserId and UserProperties at login? Would that be enough - would Firebase then just remember them for the duration the user is using the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep just send them once and the rest of the events will be attached to that user.

Firebase, and other analytics tools all behave pretty much the same way. They also will tie your user activity pre- and post-login so you can get a full picture of what actions people are taking.

Technically speaking in a React app, you’re best off adding a onAuthStateChanged call inside a useEffect hook and making the analytics call from there.